# Subset of $[a,b]$ with measure $b-a$ is dense (proof verification)

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

I want to prove that if $I$ is any finite interval, and $A\subseteq I$ satisfies $m(A)=m(I)$, then $A$ is dense in $I$.

Edit: Technically I'm given that $m(A^c) = 0$, from which it immediately follows that $A$ is measurable and that $m(A)=b-a$

The proof seemed suspiciously easy, so I just wanted to make sure that this is a legitimately easy proof, and not that it's easy because I lack sufficient imagination for pathological examples.

Proof: Let $I = [a,b]$, and let $A \subseteq I$ satisfy $m(A) = m(I) = b-a$.

We wish to show that if $(u,v)\subseteq I$, then $\exists z \in A$ such that $z\in (u,v)$.

For contradiction, assume no such $z$ exists in $(u,v)$. Then it follows that $(u,v)\subseteq A^c$ so that $m(A^c) > 0$, and thus $m(A) < b-a$.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: looks fine to me

Comment: “I implicitly use the fact that $A$ is measurable”... I don’t understate confusion (is there any??) here... The set $A$ is **given to be measurable**.. otherwise you would not be able to write $m(A)$...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik The larger problem I'm working on didn't explicitly say that $m(A)=b-a$, but rather that $A$ is a subset of $I$ and $m(A^c) = 0$.

I probably should have stated that a little more clearly.

Comment: Please edit the question accordingly.. Are you saying you have to prove $A$ is measurable and that it is dense in $I$?

Comment: Edited.

I guess I technically needed to prove measurability, but it was immediate from $m(A^c)=0$. The main question was regarding density.